# Jquery Iframe Call Top or Parent Function

Tags: jquery, function, iframe

I am having a problem with my iframe sending a variable to it's parent function. topPHP.php is my parent which has the function that is causing me problems and an iframe which loads entryPHP.php which is a form that sends a post of a pdf document to loadPHP.php which uploads the pdf to my database and calls the function of the parent topPHP.php. Sorry for the runon sentence. The result I get is as follows:

```
when topPHP.php loads the div topDiv reads "No Control"
I choose a file in the iframe (src = entryPHP.php) and hit submit
loadPHP.php is called and the file is upload to the database perfectly
In the Javascript/Jquery the alert "before the function" is called and works
After that the div topDiv still reads "No Control" and the second alert "after the function" is not called
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

topPHP:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jQuery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$( document ).ready(function() {
num = 1;

function changeDiv(num){
if(num==1)
{
$("#topDiv").val("top control");
}
if(num==2)
{
$("#topDiv").val("bottom control");
}
}
}
</script>

<iframe id="iframe_display" src="entryPHP.php" width="400" height="100">
</iframe>

<div id="topDiv">
no control
</div>
```

entryPHP:

```
<div id="uploadPDF">
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="loadPHP.php">
<table width="300" height="25" border="1">
//this table sends a pdf file as a post to loadPHP.psh
</table>
</form>
```

loadPHP:

```
<?php
//this uploads the pdf file to the database
?>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../jQuery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {

$(window).load(function(){

});
alert("before the function");
parent.changeDiv(2);
alert("after the function");

});
</script>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined your `changeDiv()` function inside the jQuery `ready()` function, and therefore it only exists in that scope, and cannot be accessed as part of the `parent` object.

To fix this problem, move the function to the global scope of your `topPHP` page, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeDiv(num){
    if(num==1)
    {
        $("#topDiv").val("top control");
    }
    if(num==2)
    {
        $("#topDiv").val("bottom control");
    }
}
$( document ).ready(function() {
    changeDiv(1);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have tried that and I get the same results. Also I have tried using top.topDiv and window.parent.topDiv, and nothing seems to work for me. Also window.changeDiv = function(num).

Comment: nm got it to work with your setting. I had a function in window.load() that was cause some problems... Thanks